# Dynamically create a selector in jquery and use 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Hopefully I can explain this properly.

I am trying not to repeat code and have a loop that binds the hover function to a specific model in a menu that shows about 30 models. I want to be able to add more models easily so I made a loop.

```
var models = ["#model1", "#model2", "#model3", "#model4", "#model5"];

for(var index = 0; index < models.length; ++index) {
   $(models[index]).hover(fadeInAndBlock, fadeOutAndUnblock);
}
```

Now this works fine. It's the fadeInAndBlock that doesn't work properly. I am trying to get some buttons to light up and the rest of the page to block.

```
function fadeInAndBlock() {
$(".productmenuinfo").block({
    overlayCSS: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        opacity: 0.6,
        cursor: "default"
    },
    message: null
});
$(this).unblock( { fadeOut: 0});


$(this + " .btnproductmoreinfo").css({
    backgroundPosition: "0px 24px"
});
$(this + " .btnproductconfigure").css({
    backgroundPosition: "0px 24px"
});
}
```

Basically, I can't get 'this' to work in the selector. I need it because the selector should be only that models buttons.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you use a common class? Than you do not have to worry about maintaining a list!

Comment: use .find, `this + " .btnproductmoreinfo"` becomes `"[object Object] .btnproductmoreinfo"` which won't select anything.

Comment: This is only used inside a jQuery function, as it refers to the object you're currently working with. In your code, this is referencing the fadeInAndBlock() function. It needs to be used within whatever selector you are using.

Comment: @rncrtr: `this` does not reference the function.

Comment: what is this in the code? It doesn't reference the selector, since it is not inside it.

Comment: @rncrtr Do you not know how jQuery sets the scope? It is a reference to the element that the event handler was bound to it. jQuery 101 stuff.

Comment: @rncrtr: Given that it's used inside a event handler, `this` will be a reference to the element to which the handler was bound. In JavaScript, it's pretty rare for `this` to refer to a function.

Comment: @squint Oh, gotcha. I was missing that part for some reason. Didn't scroll up enough. *gets off Stack and goes to get coffee* derp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `this + " .btnproductconfigure"` it is like `this.toString() + " .btnproductconfigure"` which results in `[object Object] .btnproductconfigure`.

So you need to use the object that you already have and use `find()` to get the element you are after.

So the line

```
$(this + " .btnproductconfigure").css({
```

should be

```
$(this).find(".btnproductconfigure").css({
```

Also you really should not need to maintain a list of ids. Use a common class on all the elements and you will not have to loop through and maintain the list.

Comment: How do I target just one of the models without maintaining the list of ids?

Comment: What do you mean target just one? The `this` will be only the element that is active, it does not apply to all the elements in the selector. Changing `$(".SomeCommonClass").hover(fadeInAndBlock, fadeOutAndUnblock);`, your code should work just fine.

Comment: I am trying to get just one model to be selected with $("SomeIDofaModel").hover(fadeInAndBlock, fadeOutAndUnblock); The rest get blocked and one fades in.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but the hover is activated on each model because it causes each model to fade in also. I can't use a common class because that would cause all of them to fade in hence the id.

Comment: What are you talking about? This is a watered down version: http://jsfiddle.net/4j77t/ hovering over/off one item does not change them all.

Comment: I changed it to what you said and it works but I don't understand how the $(this).unblock still works.  Also in Firefox it seems to crash and freak out and not show properly.

Comment: JQuery BlockUI doesn't seem to work with Tables across browsers and that is the problem. Looking for an alternative.  Thanks for the help epascarello!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass this as [context in selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to find in descendants.

*Syntax* `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`

```
$(".btnproductmoreinfo", this ).css({
    backgroundPosition: "0px 24px"
});
```